# Consulta PHP query

Tags: html, sql, phpmyadmin

Hola buenas tardes/noches!

Tengo una consulta, tengo conflictos por que no entiendo bien el select en el phpmyadmin, lo que quiero hacer es consultar de la tabla "plan" los datos que es 'planName', 'description' y 'validity' pero... haciendo un inner join desde la tabla usuarios donde tengo el 'pid' que es la llave primaria de mi tabla "plan", esto dependiendo de cada usuario.

Por ejemplo el usuario 1 tiene el plan 2, el usuario 2 tiene el plan 3 y asi...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El query que tengo es el siguiente...

````
$plan = "SELECT plan.planName, plan.description, plan.validity, usuarios.pid FROM plan INNER JOIN usuarios ON plan.pid=usuarios.pid where usuarios.id_usuario='$user';"; ```
````

Comment: El query está *relativamente* bien. En principio se obtiene los datos del plan según la condición. Qué es exactamente lo que estás buscando? Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado que buscas?

Comment: ¿Como le puedo hacer para que sea un insert?

Comment: `INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (4,3)`;